# Bug in unawarded badges page

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges

For example, in [meta's unsung hero badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/70/unsung-hero), it says:

> 0 Users earned this badge. Recently
>   awarded to:

It should just say:

> 0 Users earned this badge.

[image]

Comment: I think changing this to feature request asking "Change the behavior to display *No users earned this badge yet*" will have more luck of getting attention. :)

Comment: It's a pluralization bug in disguise, hide the S'es.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We'll no longer show `"Recently awarded to:"` if there aren't any awardees starting with the next build.

Comment: Had almost forgot about this one. Thanks @Nick. BTW I had lost hope with @Jeff's twit, the one about hell murder people who ask this kind of petition ;)

Answer (score -2):

I agree that it would be more convenient not have the Recently awarded to if there isn't anything to list. However it's not a major bug, or maybe not a bug at all. SE May consider changing it sometime later.

Comment: We agree that it is not major. I just wanted to report it.